# Netbeans shows only blank window

Tags: 12.04, java, netbeans

I am not able to launch Netbeans. When I launch it for the first time I normally get the netbeans splash screen, but after that nothing happens.
[image: netbeans splash screen]

When I try to launch it again, a small blank window appears.

[image: small blank window]

I am able to enlarge the window, but it is completely blank.

[image: enlarged window]

I am using openjdk-6.

Any ideas? As far as I remember this didn't come after some update/new install or whatever. Netbeans worked perfectly, but then all from the sudden...

**EDIT**

When run in terminal:

- When run for the first time:

> $ /opt/netbeans-7.1.2/bin/netbeans
>
> 10.6.2012 19:00:26 org.openide.filesystems.FileUtil normalizeFileImpl
>
> WARNING: FileUtil.normalizeFile(/home/tomas/.netbeans/7.1.2) took 569 ms. Result is /home/tomas/.netbeans/7.1.2

Then it just hangs. It doesn't quit, it just stays. If I exit (Ctrl+C) and start over again, I get the splash screen, but then again it hangs.

- When run again, while another instance is running:

  No output in terminal - just the blank screen.

Comment: I had exact same issue. And I followed the steps in https://www.codejava.net/ides/netbeans/uninstall-netbeans-from-windows This fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Though this is not the "clean" answer, I managed to launch it. This is how I did it:

- I moved the `~/.netbeans/7.1.2/` folder somewhere else. For example `mv .netbeans/7.1.2/ .netbeans/7.1.2x/`.
- I launched the NetBeans, the program asked me, if I want to import my old settings (I've had older versions of netbeans on my computer).

All my settings were as well on the older version, so I didn't lose my settings and the app is working!

Answer (score 1):

This same thing happened to me on my Windows7 machine.
The problem was that I 'lost' Java (JRE). Here is what I did:

1. From this page:  [Verify Java version](http://www.java.com/en/download/installed.jsp) , I learned that Java wasn't installed
2. I downloaded JRE from here: [Download Java](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html). You will need to figure out the right version for your machine.
3. I ran the install.
4. I started NetBeans. I got this error message:

   > Cannot locate Java is specified jdkhome.
5. Following advice from here:  [How to Fix NetBeans jdkhome error](http://arafatbd.net/post-item/142/how-to-fix-netbeans-jdkhome-error/) , I edited `netbeans.conf` to point to the new Java location.
6. Everything's alright.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling compiz or running the following in a terminal and then launching netbeans from the same terminal:

export AWT_TOOLKIT=MToolkit

And what is your Java version?

Comment: The line didn't help. I tried to launch netbeans in Unity 2D (hence there isn't compiz), but no luck. I am using openjdk-6.

Answer (score 0):

Similar problem on version 7.2.1. I was able to restore my window to default settings without losing any other config by deleting directory `~/.netbeans/7.2.1/config/Windows2Local`.